# How to convert Active Directory pwdLastSet to Date/Time

Tags: c#, datetime, active-directory, largenumber

```
    public static string GetProperty(SearchResult searchResult, string PropertyName)
    {
        if (searchResult.Properties.Contains(PropertyName))
        {
            return searchResult.Properties[PropertyName][0].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

The above method works great for most Active Directory properties except those that are related to date/time such as pwdLastSet, maxPwdAge, etc.

My question is how to I get the pwdLastSet to a human readable datetime (like 8/13/2013 or August 13, 2013, etc)

I've tries this but it threw exceptions

```
public static Int64 ConvertADSLargeIntegerToInt64(object adsLargeInteger)
{
    var highPart = (Int32)adsLargeInteger.GetType().InvokeMember("HighPart", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, adsLargeInteger, null);
    var lowPart = (Int32)adsLargeInteger.GetType().InvokeMember("LowPart", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, adsLargeInteger, null);
    return highPart * ((Int64)UInt32.MaxValue + 1) + lowPart;
}
```

I am using the following code to get the time as an Int64

```
Int64 passwordLastSet = ConvertADSLargeIntegerToInt64(objResult.Properties["pwdLastSet"][0]);
```

Then I plan on using the DateTime(Int64) constructor to create a DateTime

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679430.aspx):

> This value is stored as a large integer that represents the number of 100 nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC).

This aligns perfectly with `DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc`, [as described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromfiletimeutc.aspx).

And I'm not sure why you feel the need to do the low level manipulation of the integer.  I think you could just cast it.

So just do:

```
long value = (long)objResult.Properties["pwdLastSet"][0];
DateTime pwdLastSet = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(value);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the last password set date of a directory user in human readable form as easy as pie. To achieve this you can use nullable `LastPasswordSet` property of `UserPrincipal` class from `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace.

If `User must change password at next logon` option is checked then `LastPasswordSet` property returns `null` value. Otherwise it returns the last date and time the password was set in type `DateTime`.

```
using(PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, Username);
    //? - to mark DateTime type as nullable
    DateTime? pwdLastSet = (DateTime?)user.LastPasswordSet;
    ...
}
```

[MSDN: UserPrincipal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal_properties)
[MSDN: LastPasswordSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.authenticableprincipal.lastpasswordset)

Comment: This is a simpler solution and may be preferred over using DirectorySearcher