# DirectoryServices DirectoryEntry get pwdLastSet property c#

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices, directoryentry

I am trying to make a bool property that would toggle the pwdLastSet property.

```
public bool UserMustChangePassword
{
    get { return (long)Entry.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value == 0; }
    set
    {
        if (value) 
        {
            Entry.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value = 0; 
        }
        else 
        { 
            Entry.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value = -1; 
        }
    }                                                                                   
}
```

I can set the property successfully however I cant read the property. I keep getting the following casting error.

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Is there a specific way to read this property. I know it may be possible to `UserPrincipal`, however I would like to use `DirectoryEntry` to keep the code consistent.

**Edit**: check null before casting

```
public bool UserMustChangePassword
{
    get
    {
        var value = Entry.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value;

        if (value != null)
            return (long)Entry.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value == 0;

        return false;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value) 
        {
            Entry.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value = 0; 
        }
        else 
        { 
            Entry.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value = -1; 
        }
    }                                                                                   
}
```

Comment: Need a null check in the getter, you cannot cast null to long.

Comment: @kennyzx I had thought about that. Unfortunately I still get the same error. I also cannot cast it to a (long?)

Comment: Show how do you check against null before casting.

Comment: And what is the type of the Value property? Can it be something other than a long?

Comment: @kennyzx see above

Comment: @kennyzx thats the problem I am not exactly sure. I found that information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614810/how-to-convert-active-directory-pwdlastset-to-date-time

Comment: You can print its type information using GetType method or typeof operator, to be sure

Comment: @kennyzx they type is System.__ComObject

Comment: I notice in the post you provided, the property is accessed using index like [0], could you try it?

Comment: @kennyzx yea I tried that it doesn't work. The reason they do that is because they run a search and get back a SearchResultCollection which they index into. I have there raw DirectoryEntry so I have to access the property directly.

Comment: @Dblock247 - Can you share the extra code where `Entry` has been initialised? It is tough to identify the actual cause with the limited code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check its Count property to make sure there is a value. Try this,

```
if (Entry.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Count > 0)
{
    return (Entry.Properties["pwdLastSet"][0] == 0)
}
else 
    return false;
```

Edit:

Seems the problem comes from that you are querying Properties of DirectoryEntry instead of SearchResult. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9592422). I have a copy of working code that is also querying SearchResult.

Comment: I think the problem is the casting type. The count > 0.

Comment: A System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry instance does not have a pwdLastSet property. Have to get a SearchResultCollection and then loop through each SearchResult instance, and then get the pwdLastSet property, right?

Comment: No I am setting it just fine. The issue is getting the value. It maybe be something to do with AD INTEGER8 types to .NET
Int64. see third post here: https://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/370827-getting-pwdlastset-attrib-value-though-net

Comment: I don't know what the issue was but I found out that setting the passwordExpired flag does the same thing and I already have ways to use bitwise operators to set the flags. @kennyzx thanks for your help

Comment: Okay, np, it should be a simple issue of missing value and/or invalid type casting, glad you have found a workaround.

Comment: Just for any one who see this I think I was awrong about the passwordExpired flag. Athough it should do what I expected I believe it can only be set by the system. Every time I change it when a save the object it removes the flag. So instead I use a method called ExpirePasswordNow() (Yea I stole the name from UserPrinciple). Where I can just set the property = 0 which sets the flags.