# System.__ComObject returned when querying AD for LAPS ExpirationTime

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am using the below code to get the LAPS password and expiration date for a specific computer:

```
string computerHostName = "hostname";
string domainController = "domain.lan";

DirectoryContext dirCtx = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, domainController);
using (Domain compsDomain = Domain.GetDomain(dirCtx))
using (DirectorySearcher adSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(compsDomain.GetDirectoryEntry()))
{
    //this is the search criteria for the domain query
    adSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=computer) (cn=" + computerHostName + "))";
    adSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    adSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("ms-Mcs-AdmPwd");
    adSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime");
    SearchResult searchResult = adSearcher.FindOne();
    
    //Get the LAPS password
    Console.WriteLine(searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["ms-Mcs-AdmPwd"].Value);
    //Should get the LAPS password expiration time
    Console.WriteLine(searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime"].Value);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

However, the output looks like this:

> [LAPS password here]
>
> System.__ComObject

I have tried looking online and have already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819458/how-to-get-a-system-comobject-value-from-active-directory-in-c-sharp) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56021248/system-comobject-instead-of-active-directory-values?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I still can't get it to work. How can I get the script to output the expiration time normally?

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18619065/17034

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for the link, I never found that.. oops. I have added it as an answer to this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hans Passant referred me to this link: [How to convert Active Directory pwdLastSet to Date/Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614810/how-to-convert-active-directory-pwdlastset-to-date-time/18619065#18619065)

Instead of using:

```
Console.WriteLine(searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime"].Value);
```

I should instead use:

```
Console.WriteLine((long)searchResult.Properties["ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime"][0]);
```

which Correctly outputs:

> 132068789141660751

Comment: The reason for this is that `DirectoryEntry.Properties` returns the value as an [`IADsLargeInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iads/nn-iads-iadslargeinteger), which you have to read using that `ConvertADSLargeIntegerToInt64` method in [the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614810/how-to-convert-active-directory-pwdlastset-to-date-time). `SearchResult.Properties` presents the value as a `long`, which you can just pass to `DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc`. I don't know why the difference.

Comment: In this case, you should be reading from the `SearchResult` anyway, since you already asked for the value in the results (using `PropertiesToLoad`). Using `searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties` actually ends up going back out to AD and reading every attribute from the object, which is just unnecessary.